# How to loop through an element with .each() and check if the element matches with an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm trying to loop through a bunch of h1's with :contains. It works if I use 1 keyword, but I'm trying to use :contains with multiple keywords. For now, I'm using localStorage, saving the keyword and then calling it in the selector, but this only works for 1 keyword which is what I don't want.

HTML

```
<div class="item1">
    <h1>Silk</h1>
</div>
<div class="item2">
    <h1>Champion</h1>
</div>
<div class="item3">
    <h1>Smooth</h1>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
itemKeyword1 = localStorage["Keyword1"];
$("h1:contains('" + itemKeyword1 + "'").each(function(){
            //do something

})
```

I want to make an array `var array = ['Silk','Champion'];`and make the `.each()` search for these keywords from the array in the `h1`'s and then return them or just do something with it.

Comment: Some accompanying HTML might be helpful.  Not too much though ;)  Just enough to help

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I've added some simple HTML. I just want my each statement to return all the h1's containing the words from the array.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking, how localStorage works or how to search for multiple items in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you want "and", you can do multiple filter() operations to narrow down selection.

```
$("h1:contains('" + itemKeyword1 + "'").filter("h1:contains('" + itemKeyword2 + "'")
```

If you want "or", just give comma separated list of multiple selectors to jQuery.

```
$("h1:contains('" + itemKeyword1 + "',h1:contains('" + itemKeyword2 + "'")
```

For more complex "or" cases select them separately and then merge.

```html
<div class="item1">
    <h1>Silk</h1>
</div>
<div class="item2">
    <h1>Champion</h1>
</div>
<div class="item3">
    <h1>Smooth</h1>
</div>
<div class="item3">
    <h1>Smooth and Silk</h1>
</div>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script type="text/javascript">

var keywords = ['Silk','Smooth'];

var $items = $();
$.each(keywords, function(key, value){
    $items = $items.add("h1:contains('" + value + "')");
});

$.uniqueSort($items).each(function(){
   // do your stuff
   $(this).css({'border':'1px solid red'});
});

</script>
```

Comment: I've tried this before and I know it works, but I want to use an array for this as I've been working on saving keywords via an input using commas and then putting it in an array for the .each() to use. Using two localStorage variables would just make this inconvenient. What If I want to use twelve keywords? I'd have to copy paste that :contains selector 12 times which feels stupid and I feel like there's a better way to do this using an array, I just don't know how.

Comment: Create empty jQuery selector and then start to merge there in loop over your localStorage array?

Comment: :contains with multiple comma separated words doesn't work IIRC

Comment: The $.uniqueSort isn't working for me. It says it isn't a function

Comment: Added newer jQuery than yours to my sample and made this a snippet. Works in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalStorage` stores values in string format. Since, you are storing array in the localStorage, it will be converted to string. To convert back the string to array, you have to `JSON.parse()` it.
After that using [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) you can iterate through the words in array.

```js
var localStorageStored = '["Silk","Champion"]';
var stored = JSON.parse(localStorageStored);
var result = [];
$.each(stored, function(index,value) {
  var temp = $("h1:contains('"+value+"')");
  if(temp)
    result.push(temp)
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1">
  <h1>Silk</h1>
</div>
<div class="item2">
    <h1>Champion</h1>
</div>
<div class="item3">
    <h1>Smooth</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function on the selected `h1` elements;

```js
var headings = ['Silk','Champion']; 
var h1s =  $('h1').filter(function() { 
              return headings.indexOf($(this).text()) != -1; 
           });
alert(h1s.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Silk</h1>
<h1>Champion</h1>
<h1>Smooth</h1>
```